# How to fork a non github repo to github without cloning to my system?

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to fork a non github repo to git hub,
since I have a slow connection I can't afford it to clone to my system and push to github

thanks,

Comment: Just to clarify, you primarily want to avoid *pushing* the repo from your slow connection? (wasn't clearly stated, I initially thought you wanted to avoid cloning the repo, which seemed.. strange!)

Comment: nope , instead of cloning first and pushing to github , I want to fork it in github and then clone. :)

Comment: is that because your *upload* speed slow compared to the *download* speed?

Comment: if forking directly to github is possible , then I can save the time to pull the cloned repo to github right?. in that case only the modified files have to be pushed to the repo.

Comment: now what the only way i see  is 

1- clone the original repo to my system 
2- push it to my github repo 
3- start working on my local repo 
4- push it to github

but if i can fork directly there , then 
1- fork it on github
2- clone it to my local system
3- work on the local repo 
4- push changes to github 

I think the second way is better (if there is a way to achieve it :) )

Comment: now I understand your point :) Instead of transferring the full repo twice (clone and push), you only need to do full transfer once (clone) if the github clone is already there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could clone it to a remote server using SSH and then push it to github from there, but that's the only option I know of.

Alternatively, look to see if someone else has already uploaded it if it's open source, then you can fork it on github and just push the much smaller set of updates from your local machine. If you know someone else with a fast connection, you could ask them to do this for you, or else upload it and then change ownership of the repo to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, unless the repository is SVN, in which case you can use the [Import from Subversion](http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/) feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell on existing host you can push from it to Github

Comment: I don't have shell access to the original repo , :(

Comment: @Arackna - follow Matt advice in this case